# MS Excel worksheet change event - keeping record of old cell value against new value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to this forum but have been building up my coding experience in the last couple of months due to the VBA requirements of my current role. Today's problem has seen me trawling through many sites (and my Excel VBA for Dummies book), but I haven't quite nailed it.

I am trying to make an audit tracker file in Excel for our company Risk Register. The idea is that once the risk register is established, any changes will create an audit trail (on a separate tab) which shows both the old and the new record.

I have written the code using the Change Event handler. I want my macro to fire every time there is a change and do the following:
**1.** Make a reference of the old cell value (what the user has just overwritten)
**2.** Jump to the 'Audit trail' tab and paste two copies of the full risk record - each risk record is a row of data that occupies 17 columns
**3.** In the first copy of these 17 columns, work out which column was edited and replace this cell with the old cell value (captured in step 1)
**4.** Insert a time stamp
**5.** Have conditional formatting highlight the record that has changed [this function is not required in the code as I've set it up within the spreadsheet itself]
**6.** Jump back to cell where the user just made their edit (on the 'Risk Register' tab)

I have managed steps 1, 2 and 4-7 but I am having problems getting the code to input the "old cell value" into the right spot in the 'Audit Tracker' tab. I can get it there if I manually define the cell range for it to paste into, but I can't seem to make it dynamic so that it will automatically recognize what field the user is changing and ensure the same field is amended in the audit trail.

Would really appreciate any insights as to why the "*PasteRange.Value = Worksheets("Risk Register").Range("oldValuePaste")*" line isn't working

My code is as follows:

```
    Dim oldValue As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b13:r13")) Is Nothing Then
                oldValue = Target.Value
            End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b13:r14")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> oldValue Then
            'MsgBox "You just changed " & Target.Address
             Cells(65, 5).Value = oldValue       'this cell is a named range called: OldValuePaste
             Cells(66, 5).Value = Target.row     'this cell is a named range called: OldValueRowNumber
             Cells(67, 5).Value = Target.Column  'this cell is a named range called: OldValueColumnNumber

            Range(Cells(Target.row, 2), Cells(Target.row, 18)).Copy
            'Cells(70, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            Call Paste_on_AuditSheet
            Sheets("Risk Register").Activate
            Target.Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End If
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

_____________________________________________________________________________________________________

Sub Paste_on_AuditSheet()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ColNum As Long
Dim PasteRange As Range
ColNum = OldValueColumnNumber

    Sheets("Audit trail").Select
    'MsgBox "Activated " & ActiveSheet.Name

        'Find the last used row in a Column: column B in this example
        With ActiveSheet
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
        End With

    Set PasteRange = Cells(LastRow, ColNum)

'The following two lines bring in the new data and paste into old record and new record sections:
        Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Cells(LastRow + 1, 20).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Then this line goes back over the piece just pasted in and changes one cell in "old record" section to what it was prior to the edit:
        'PasteRange.Value = Worksheets("Risk Register").Range("oldValuePaste")
'Above line of code is not working, but can get it to do the right thing using this code (although it's not dynamic):
        Range("E3").Value = Worksheets("Risk Register").Range("oldValuePaste")

'Add a time stamp:
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = Now

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

One last point - despite my repeated use of Application.ScreenUpdating commands, I still get some screen flashing - any ideas why?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: very quickly on the `ScreenUpdating` remove the `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` from the `Paste_on_AuditSheet` Sub. It turns it back on for the rest of the code in the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reviewing your code, I saw a few things that I didn't think would work as you supposed they would, and also recognized that your code could be made much simpler and just be called from the `Worksheet_Change` event.

So the refactored code below and let me know if you have issues:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b13:r14")) Is Nothing Then

    'get oldValue
    Dim sNewVal As String, sOldVal As String
    sNewValue = Target.Value 'store current or "new" value since this is what is stored after the cell change takes place
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False 'turns off event firing so the code will not go into endless loop
        .Undo 'undo the change (to store old value in next line)
    End With
    sOldValue = Target.Value 'store old value
    Target.Value = sNewValue 'reset new value

    Dim lCol As Long
    lCol = Target.Column 'which column of data was changed 

    'assumes columns A-Q are 17 columns
    Me.Range(Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1), Me.Cells(Target.Row, 17)).Copy

    With Sheets("Audit Trail")

        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

        .Range("B" & lRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("B" & lRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("A" & lRow).Value = Now

        .Cells(lRow, lCol + 1).Value = sOldValue 'store old value in first pasted line ... add 1 since starting from column B

    End With

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This will have problems if Target is not a single cell, and also when Target is multi-cell but only *some* of those cells are in B13:R14 it would (if it worked with >1 cell) still process the whole of the `Target` range instead of just the part within B13:R14.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @TimWilliams. I'll let OP tell me if he needs adjustments for these issues.

Comment: Fantastic effort @ScottHoltzman - thank you so much for your help. I've taken your suggestions and used it to simplify my code. Critically that Target value string is all working and along with the lCol = Target.Column dimension. I've made a few minor amendments to suit: have set it up so the old and new records are side by side on the 'Audit Trail' tab (rather than one below the other) and also used your tip to sort the screen updating issue I had.

Comment: Thanks also to @TimWilliams for the point about the multi-cell. Have no merged cells so this shouldn't cause an issue for me. Cheers guys