# Copy and Paste changes in rows on one sheet due to a macro to the next free row on another sheet

Tags: excel

I am looking for help in completing a macro that copies changes due to a macro on one sheet to another. The macro already copies the date and username of the person submitting the changes to another sheet but I would like to copy the rows that have been changed as well underneath the date and username.

This is what I have already and it works fine but all I know now is who submitted changes and not what he changes were.

```
*Range("D1").Value = Environ("Username")
Sheets("UNI").Range("B1:D1").Copy
     Sheets("Record").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
         Paste:=xlPasteValues
     Application.CutCopyMode = False*
```

On sheet1 Column E gets changed when the macro is submitted so if this IS changed then I want to copy the entire row that the cell is in and copy it to "Record"

This has been driving me crazy for weeks. Please could you help

Comment: instead of copying Range B:D you can use `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy` and then paste entire row. as `...Offset(1,0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial....`

Comment: review the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511913/ms-excel-worksheet-change-event-keeping-record-of-old-cell-value-against-new-v/35512615#35512615). You'll need to adjust the code (cell references, etc.) to meet your specific needs, but the structure and concept will serve you well with your needs.